# Do we need a Sharepoint server for creating web part for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, web-part, sharepoint-server

When we are creating a SharePoint web part from Visual Studio, it requires a physical SharePoint Server installed on the machine. It shows the below error

[image: SharePoint server error]

How can we create a SharePoint Webpart for SharePoint Online without Sharepoint server?

Comment: Please check this link :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg454741(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hi, this will be clear, can you please answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

You've not selected the correct project template. That error is shown when you try to create a On-Premises SharePoint 2013 solution on a non-SharePoint development environment. To create solutions for SharePoint Online, you should create a project using the App for SharePoint project template.

Comment: Ok thanks James. For web part creation what we need to do?